# iPhone: How to higthlight word of UILabel

Tags: iphone

I would like to highlight a word which in an `UILabel` which is placed on an `UITabelViewCell`.

What I would like to do is set a background color for just that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `UILabel` does not support this, you will need to use [`CoreText`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which wil make easier to use `CoreText`.

And grab [`NSAttributedString+Attributes`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) for east manipulation of `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Or instead of using `TTTAttributedLabel` in one hand and the `NSAttributedString+Attributes` file from `OHAttributedLabel` on the other hand, why not using only the `OHAttributedLabel` library that provides it all (label subclass to mask the CoreText underlying code + `NSAttributedString` category, all at once) ? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot use a UILabel for this. However, you do have options:

1. Use a UIWebView instead and set CSS for doing your highlight

   > ```
   > <html>
   >   <head>
   >     ...
   >   </head>
   >   <body>How is it <span class="highlight">going</span></body>
   > </html>
   > ```
2. Use a custom label library: [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) or [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)
3. Add a custom UIView behind your label and postion it over the text
4. Look into [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html) and create your own custom label

I'd strongly recommend looking at the second option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You need to make several UILabels for separating highlighted text from unhighlighted and put them one by one and, just setting background color of highlighted ones.

... or, don't use UILabel at all, if your text is dynamyc and it will be hard to separate words.